# Tauri window.__TAURI__.fs.readDir(... is unable to read directory - Error: path not allowed on the configured scope

Tags: scope, filesystems, tauri

I'm new to Tauri and I'm trying to read / ls a directory.

> window.**TAURI**.fs.readDir("com.tauri.dev/", { dir: window.**TAURI**.fs.Dir.Data }).then(...
>
> Unhandled Promise Rejection: path not allowed on the configured scope: /home/user/.local/share/com.tauri.dev/

It seems like I'm messing up the scope somehow? I've enabled every "allowlist" item I could think of and the scope seems to be defined correctly:

```
"allowlist": {
  "path": { "all": true },
  "all": true,
  "fs": {
    "all": true,
    "readFile": true,
    "writeFile": true,
    "readDir": true,
    "copyFile": true,
    "createDir": true,
    "removeDir": true,
    "removeFile": true,
    "renameFile": true,
    "scope": ["$DATA/com.tauri.dev/*"]
  }
```

What gives?

---

Tauri info:

```
$ npm run tauri info

> tauri-app@0.0.0 tauri
> tauri "info"


Environment
  › OS: Pop!_OS 21.10 X64
  › Node.js: 17.7.0
  › npm: 8.5.2
  › pnpm: Not installed!
  › yarn: 1.22.17
  › rustup: 1.24.3
  › rustc: 1.59.0
  › cargo: 1.59.0
  › Rust toolchain: stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu 

Packages
  › @tauri-apps/cli [NPM]: 1.0.0-rc.7(outdated, latest: 1.0.0-rc.8)
  › @tauri-apps/api [NPM]: 1.0.0-rc.3(outdated, latest: 1.0.0-rc.3)
  › tauri [RUST]: 1.0.0-rc.6,
  › tauri-build [RUST]: 1.0.0-rc.5,
  › tao [RUST]: 0.7.0,
  › wry [RUST]: 0.14.0,

App
  › build-type: bundle
  › CSP: unset
  › distDir: ../dist
  › devPath: http://localhost:3000/
  › framework: Svelte

App directory structure
  ├─ .vscode
  ├─ js
  ├─ node_modules
  ├─ public
  ├─ css
  ├─ src
  ├─ img
  ├─ src-tauri
  ├─ old_nm
  ├─ doc
  └─ data
```

Comment: "scope": ["*"] fixes the problem, but it's not very secure..

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems with the `scope` in `http` for tauri version `1.0.0-rc.3`.

Saw some fixes for the scope on tauri dev and upgraded to an unreleased git backed version (in `Cargo.toml`):

```
tauri = { git = "https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/", rev="834ccc51539401d36a7dfa1c0982623c9c446a4c", features = ["fs-read-file", "fs-write-file", "http-all",...
```

Fixed the HTTP issue and also `fs` is working for me (in `tauri.conf.json`)

```
"allowlist": {
            "fs": {
                "readFile": true,
                "writeFile": true,
                "scope": ["$DATA/XXX/**"]
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it needs both the base path and the one with the * appended in order to work in the directory you are referencing.

```
"scope": ["$APP/*","$APP"]
```

Answer (score 0):

i did't wanna Risk it so
so I use both answer
like this

```
  "scope": [
      "$APPDATA/*","$APPDATA", "$APPDATA/**",
    "$RESOURCE/soundPack/*","$RESOURCE/soundPack/**","$RESOURCE/soundPack"]
```